# materialize tab error, tab2 showing with tab1

Tags: tabs, materialize

I am using materialize with vue.js I have a weird error

```
<div class="row">
<form class="col s12">
<ul class="tabs tabs-fixed-width">
      <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#main">Main</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a  href="#extra">Extra</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="main" class="col">Main</div>
<div id="main" class="col">Extra</div>
</form>
</div>
```

When I enter on tab2 it shows tab2, but when I enter on tab1 it shows also the content of tab2.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to change the `id` attribute for the second `<div>`. You need to change:

```
<div id="main" class="col">Extra</div>
```

To:

```
<div id="extra" class="col">Extra</div>
```

Comment: thanks, my original id was "extra" and it should have been "extras"

Comment: Happy to help, if this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.